# css3 media queries js conflicts with fancybox

Tags: css, plugins, fancybox, media-queries

I am trying to use css3 media queries js from google code in conjunction with fancybox.

For some reason they conflict only in Internet explorer 9 and 10.  Ie8 works fine as well as well as Google Chrome, and Mozilla Firefox.

@hen I use the CSS3 media queries javascript plug-in, and click on a fancybox popup, the fancybox popup is left blank.  It shows the popup but with no content inside.  What also happens is that when I click the fancybox popup, the original layout where the fancybox is activated, becomes scaled (huge ) while the popup is the correct width/height.

When i remove the css3 media queries, everything is fine again.  Thank you for any help.

these are all the scripts used in my magento's page.xml from the layout folder:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery/no_conflict.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery.lazyload.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/loadlazy.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/vendor/bootstrap.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery.cookie.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery.fancybox-media.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery-ias.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/ias-load.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

                <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/bootstrap-modal.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

                <action method="addJs"><script>js/css3-mediaqueries.js</script></action>
            </block>
```

this is how i call the fancybox plugin:

```
$jq191(".product-popup").fancybox({
        fitToView   : true,
        padding: 15,
        maxWidth    : browserWidth-25,
        maxHeight   : browserHeight-25,
        width        : '100%',
        height              : '100%',
        autoSize    : false,
        autoResize      : false,
        autoCenter      : true,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        type: 'iframe',
        helpers : { overlay : { locked : false
                     } },
        afterShow : function(){
            var marginPercentage= 0.0706955530216648*2;
            viewWidth= browserWidth - marginPercentage*browserWidth;
            $jq191( '.product-view' ).width( viewWidth+'px');
        }
    });
```

and thats all im doing, i don't think theres anything else thats relevant to the problem with the conflict but if you know any please let me know and i will post. thanks.

Comment: it would be good if you show your code and set a live example of the issue, a jsfiddle for instance.

Comment: well i'm using magento in combination with fancybox, and the css3 media queries js just needs to be included for it to work. ill edit my post so i can show what scripts are being used that may be conflicting. basically i just include css3-media queries js without any specific call to it or anything.  thanks for the quick reply.